# xml - how to create/run XML file

Tags: xml

Can someone advise me on what I need to run an .xml file? Can I create it in Notepad
and save it with an .xml extension then double click the file whilst in Windows or do
I need a special editor?

I have a java application and want to use Jave Web Start techonology which requires
a JNLP file from my .jar file.

Thanks

Comment: XML is text - it can't "run" on anything. A program can read XML, interpret it and do something with the info.

Comment: you can open an xml file with notepad. Or even better try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). The default application to open a file for a given extension (.xml in this case) can be changed to the application of your choice.

Comment: Should be tagged `confusion-of-ideas`. See @Oded: XML is data, you don't run data. Plain text data by the way, so no special editor needed (but a decent text editor is very helpful - +1 for Notepad++).

Comment: @delnan, I wonder why that tag does not exists... :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can run an xml file. To be exact: you can run an xsl file, which is a special kind of xml with xslt code, but also pure text just as other source code. The interpreter on which the xslt script runs is your browser.
So you need two files:

a. An xml file containing the data and the information which script to use (name it "test.xml"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>  
<root>data</root>
```

b. An xsl file containing the script (name it "test.xsl"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">  
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Show XML</title>
      <head>
      <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If your OS doesn't know which program to use on opening the xml file, tell him it's the browser.
And yes, you only need any editor like notepad and any browser like firefox or ie. Using one which knows xml is more convinient, but notepad and ie are already a complete development environment - standanlone, without needing any java, so I don't know why you mention it.

Comment: How did you get the XML file is actually a XSLT transformation?

Comment: I did not get the XML file is actually a XSLT transformation, but it takes a second XML file that is one to get the "run on double click" effect. At least this is the only common way to get it done, which works on almost every PC.

Comment: It does not work, can you clarify the way which u do it

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple Insert into an xml file using C#

{
invoke method first..............

```
   public void InvokeKey()
    {
        DSXml.ReadXml(@"c:\users\general\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\xml_practice\xml_practice\todolist.xml");

        DataColumn[] ID = new DataColumn[1];

        ID[0] = DSXml.Tables[0].Columns[0];

        DSXml.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = ID;
    }
```

DataSet DsXml = new DataSet();
        DataRow DrXML;

```
    string Date = Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("d"));
    string Time = Convert.ToString(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));

    int ID;




    InvokeKey();
            DRXML = DSXml.Tables[0].Rows.Find(ID);

    DsXml.WriteXml(@"path");

        DrXML = DsXml.Tables[0].NewRow();

        DrXML[0] = ID;
        DrXML[0] = ID;
        DrXML[0] = ID;
        DrXML[0] = ID;
        DrXML[0] = ID;
        DrXML[0] = ID;

        DsXml.Tables[0].Rows.Add(DrXML);

        DsXml.WriteXml(@"path");
```

dt = REport.LoadSubjects();

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application(); // open app
        xlApp.Visible = true;

        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1); //open workbook
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[1]; //open worksheet


        xlSheet.Cells.Rows.Columns.AutoFit(); 

        string strTempVariable = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();   //temporary variable

        xlSheet.Cells[4, 1] = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();

        xlSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Employees group header";

        for (int count = 0; count < dt.Columns.Count;count++ )
        {
            xlSheet.Cells[3, count+1] = dt.Columns[count].ColumnName;// prints column names
        }
        int group=0;
        int total=0;
        int intRow = 5;//manages xlsheet

        for (int counter = 0; counter < dt.Rows.Count;counter++ )
        {
            if (strTempVariable == dt.Rows[counter]["City"].ToString())
            {
                xlSheet.Cells[intRow, 2] = dt.Rows[counter][1];
                xlSheet.Cells[intRow, 3] = dt.Rows[counter][2];
                xlSheet.Cells[intRow, 4] = dt.Rows[counter][3];
                xlSheet.Cells[intRow, 5] = dt.Rows[counter][4];
                group++;
                total++;
                intRow++;
            }
            else
            {
                xlSheet.Cells[intRow, 4] = "group name  " + strTempVariable + "  " + group.ToString();

                strTempVariable = dt.Rows[counter][0].ToString();
                intRow++;
                xlSheet.Cells[intRow, 1] = strTempVariable;
                intRow++;
                counter--;
                group = 0;
            }

        }
          intRow++;
       xlSheet.Cells[intRow, 4] = "group name  " + strTempVariable + "  "+group.ToString();  
             intRow++;
        xlSheet.Cells[intRow, 4] = "GrandTotal  " + "  "+total.ToString();



        xlWorkBook.Close(true, "GROUP REPORT", 0);//The name of the worksheet

        xlApp.Quit();

       // return "Report Successfully";

    }
```

public string ReportTimeTable()
        {

```
        DataTier.clsDataAccess Data = new DataTier.clsDataAccess();

        int intCount = 0;
        int intCount2 = 5;


        Data.sqlcon.Close();
        Data.sqlcon.Open();


        Data.sqlAdpter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY password",Data.sqlcon);
        DataTable ReportDt = new DataTable("Report");

        Data.sqlAdpter.Fill(ReportDt);
        Data.sqlcon.Close();

       string strMsg = "";

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;



        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];


        // Setting cell values
        ((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[1, "A"]).Value2 = "Report - USERS "; //main heading

        ((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[3, "A"]).Value2 = "USERNAME"; //field headings
        ((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[3, "B"]).Value2 = "PASSWORD";
       // ((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[3, "C"]).Value2 = "MARK";


        for (intCount = 0; intCount < ReportDt.Rows.Count; intCount++)
        {
            xlWorksheet.Cells[intCount2, "A"] = ReportDt.Rows[intCount][0];
            xlWorksheet.Cells[intCount2, "B"] = ReportDt.Rows[intCount][1];
           // xlWorksheet.Cells[intCount2, "C"] = ReportDt.Rows[intCount][2];


            intCount2++;
        }
        xlWorksheet.Cells.Columns.AutoFit();
        strMsg = "report successful";
        return strMsg;
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a special editor, but that can help a lot while editing.

You cannot run an xml-file. But you can run a program which uses the xml-file.

To "run" the xml file, you probably need something like the following statement:

```
java -jar yourFile.jar packageOfMainMethod.ClassWithMainMethod yourXML.xml
```

But this depends on the program you try to run.

Comment: I just want to create a JNLP file from my xml file but it is complaining of the address can I use a codebase that is a local dir on my harddisk to create the JNLP?

Comment: this is my xml file to create a JNLP all I get is aNavigation to webpage cancelled even though I am specifying that my jar is in my c:\users.. dir <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!-- JNLP File for TableDemo --> <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="C:/Users/" href="TableDemo.jnlp"> <information> <title>TableDemo</title> <description>Java Table Demo </description> <offline-allowed/> </information> <resources> <jar href="TableDemo.jar" /> <j2se version="1.6+"> </resources> <application-desc main-class="TableDemo" /> </jnlp>